# Matching strings with multiple words between two words

Tags: lua, coronasdk, lua-patterns

In my program, I am trying match a string that has two letters and then a few words between them like such: `"! hello my name !"` In this example, the string `"hello my name"` can change in the number of words to a string such as: `"hello"` or even more words. Anyways, how can I match the string between the exclamation marks? The main problem is that I cannot figure out the expression to use in the string match to represent a string with multiple words of an unknown length.

Comment: You probably need to look at regular expressions.

Comment: I have, but I cannot find any for a sequence of words where the number of words can have a variable length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the pattern `!([^!]+)!`, in which `[^!]*` matches zero or more characters that aren't `!`.

```
print(string.match("! hello my name !","!([^!]*)!"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try also the pattern `"!(.-)!"`.

This matches the *shortest* string of this form, unlike `"!(.*)!"`, which matches the *longest* one.